# passing system variable inside another variable

Tags: windows, batch, desktop-icons, autocad

My issue: I need to copy specific icons to user desktops that point to various engrg resources. These icons update somewhat regularly. My initial batch file was simply using `robocopy` to do this, and worked perfectly.

```
robocopy "[NetworkDrive]\folderX\Desktop" "%userprofile%\Desktop"
```

At least it did for most people. As we deploy office365 and onedrive, people are syncing their desktop. In this case, The %userprofile%\desktop is not the location of the desktop. Its something much different:

```
c:\users\username\one_drive_enterprise_name\Desktop
```

So I adjusted my batch like this:

```
set KEY_NAME="HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders"

set VALUE_NAME="Desktop"

FOR /F "skip=2 tokens=2,*" %%A IN ('reg.exe query %KEY_NAME% /v %VALUE_NAME%') DO SET LUD=%%B

echo "%LUD%"

robocopy "[NetworkDrive]\folderX\Desktop" "%LUD%"
```

`%LUD%` returns the appropriate key for the given user.

I get either `%userprofile%\desktop` OR `"c:\users\username\one_drive_enterprise_name\Desktop."`

But when I pass `%LUD%` inside robocopy, it takes it as literal path and prefixes it with the current location of the batch file.

c:\users\current user\desktop\userprofile\desktop as an example.

I end up with a new folder called %userprofile% on the desktop with a subfolder called Desktop. :)

How do I pass the appropriate with using another If>Then with simple hard coded paths?

Thanks
Kevin

Comment: I'm sure it has to do with trying to include a variable inside another variable... I'm just too tired to see the forest for the trees.... :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the value of the `LUD` variable contains `%` characters to reference another variable.

Maybe there's a more efficient way, but you could do something like this:

```
echo set folder=%LUD% > "%TEMP%\setfolder.bat"
call "%TEMP%\setfolder.bat"
del "%TEMP%\setfolder.bat"
echo %folder%
```

Comment: i will give this a try, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should fix it, it gets the content of the variables inside %LUD% rather than the variable itself:

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('echo %LUD%') do set LUD=%%a

```
@echo off
set KEY_NAME="HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders"

set VALUE_NAME="Desktop"

FOR /F "skip=2 tokens=2,*" %%A IN ('reg.exe query %KEY_NAME% /v %VALUE_NAME%') DO SET LUD=%%B

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('echo %LUD%') do set LUD=%%a

robocopy "[NetworkDrive]\folderX\Desktop" "%LUD%"
```

Comment: i will give this a try as well!

Answer (score 0):

In talking with some co-workers, i have two other options...

1 - just use the public desktop for everyone and call it a day.
C:\users\public\desktop

2 - use the "Shell Folder" key instead of "User Shell Folder". Why? because the 'shell folder' key only holds the actual paths, no variables. IOW, delete 'user' from the KEY_NAME.